# C# Kill all threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application that invokes my DLL with `InvokeMember()` like so:

```
Assembly OCA = Assembly.LoadFrom("./Modules/ProcessFiles.dll");
Type[] types = OCA.GetTypes();
foreach (var type in types)
{
    //MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
    if (type.Name == "Converter")
    {
        var tmpType = type;
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(tmpType);
        Thread t = new Thread(
            () =>
            tmpType.InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj,
            null));
        t.Start();
        break;
    }

}
```

My DLL then creates new a thread and starts processing. In my DLL, I the create new thread like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
    delegate(){
        while(true)
        {
            GetFilesInFolder();
            Thread.Sleep(120000);
        }
    });
ne.Start();
```

The goal is to periodically check the folder. The problem is that when I close the application that invokes my DLL, the process is not closed. Is there a way to close all the threads?

NB: I can’t modify the application, I can only modify my DLL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property of the thread to `true`. This will kill the thread when your app finishes.

Also: Why don't you use one timer (or just one thread), that wakes and eximines the data. That should be more resource friendly.

Comment: I did try to use timer but i couldnt get the Threading.Timer working.

Comment: Yes, i know about that allso. Maybe you can give me a working example how to use the Timer in my situation?

Comment: `new Timer(GetFilesInFolder, null, 1000, 12000); Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` This is how i tryied to use the timer, but it still executed the method just once.

Comment: Well, if you use a Timer then obviously it doesn't make sense to put the timer thread to sleep for an infinite amount of time. Just delete the "Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);" line and you should be good.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using a [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)? this throws events when something changes in a folder. It looks like this will simplify your solution.

Comment: Yes, im using `FileSystemWatcher` allso for new files and chenges. But its bit more compilcated. Some files are just not ready to process and i have to leave them in that folder and come check up on them later.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing Safe Cancellation from [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker)

```
class RulyCanceler
{
  object _cancelLocker = new object();
  bool _cancelRequest;
  public bool IsCancellationRequested
  {
    get { lock (_cancelLocker) return _cancelRequest; }
  }

  public void Cancel() { lock (_cancelLocker) _cancelRequest = true; } 

  public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
  {
    if (IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException();
  }
}
```

Test

```
class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var canceler = new RulyCanceler();
    new Thread (() => {
                        try { Work (canceler); }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                          Console.WriteLine ("Canceled!");
                        }
                      }).Start();
    Thread.Sleep (1000);
    canceler.Cancel();               // Safely cancel worker.
  }

  static void Work (RulyCanceler c)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      c.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      // ...
      try      { OtherMethod (c); }
      finally  { /* any required cleanup */ }
    }
  }

  static void OtherMethod (RulyCanceler c)
  {
    // Do stuff...
    c.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background thread mentioned above or timer:

```
Timer checkTimer;
public void StartTimer()
{
    checkTimer = new Timer(s => GetFilesInFolder(), null, 0, 120000);
}
```

Don't forget to Dispose it.